# history.js Pushstate not updating the browser URL when making an ajax call through code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, history.js

I am using history.js in my website. I am using mvc views and Ajax to display the content. I am new to history.js so please help me.
My website should not allow a user to go back. If the user clicks the back button, I am redirecting them to the latest entry in the history savedstate with an alert saying not to click the back button.

Below is the code I include to handle the statechange event

```
(function (window, undefined) {

    var History = window.History;
    if (!History.enabled) {
        return false;
    }
    History.options.disableSuid = true;

// Bind to State Change

 // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
   History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () { 

      // below suggestion found on the forum for back button
      var currentIndex = History.getCurrentIndex();
      var internal = (History.getState().data._index == (currentIndex - 1));
      if (!internal) {
           alert("Please do not click the back button");    }

      History.go(History.savedStates.length - 1);
  });
 })(window);

 function HistoryPushState(PartialUrl) {
     var History = window.History;
     if (!History.enabled) {
         return false;
     }
     History.pushState({ _index: History.getCurrentIndex() }, $("title").text(),     PartialUrl);
 }
}
```

I am loading the ajax content on the submit button of the form. I call the HistoryPushState('/Index/NewPartialView') on the partial view of mine.

```
 <div id="replacecontent">

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         var form = $("#replacecontent").closest("form");
         form.removeData('validator');
         form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
         $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#replacecontent"));

         HistoryPushState('/Index/NewPartialView');
     });
 </script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
 ----- ajax html content
 }

My concern... I load the 'Index/Index' page and call the HistoryPushState(), I click the submit button on the 'Index/Index' page and make an ajax call to '/Index/NewPartialView'.  HistoryPushState() is called when the '/Index/NewPartialView' is rendered. The '/Index/NewPartialView' entry gets added into the History savedstates queue. 

But the browser url remains http://mydomain/Index/Index instead of getting updated to    'http://localhost/Index/NewPartialView'. This happens sometimes, not all the time.

This is creating an unexpected behavior when the user clicks the browser refresh, then    instead of loading 'http://mydomain/Index/NewPartialView' (I am handling full page    load as well as partial ajax calls) it loads the current browser url content http://mydoamin/Index/Index
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated. I need to prevent a user from going back and displaying an alert if they do.